# Generic Tensorflow.js training example

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js, synaptic.js

I'm trying to train neural network to do some image processing. I successfully did it with Synaptic.js, but it learns terribly slow when I have to use more layers. Tensorflow.js samples describe some specific cases and it's hard to understand them and apply to my case. Could anybody help me with converting this Synaptic.js code into Tensorflow.js? Input is a 3x3 (or more) kernel of RGB pixels [0..1] and output is a single RGB pixel [0..1]

```
const layers = [27, 9, 3];
const learningRate = 0.05;
const perceptron = new Synaptic.Architect.Perceptron(layers);

// Train
sampleData.forEach(([input, output]) => {
    perceptron.activate(input);
    perceptron.propagate(learningRate, output);
});

// Get result
const result = realData.map((input) => perceptron.activate(input));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some very generic TensorFlow.js examples in the examples repo:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples

For your case you will need to do something like the iris example in that repo.

```
// Define the model.
const model = tf.sequential();
// you will need to provide the size of the individual inputs below 
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 27, inputShape: INPUT_SHAPE})); 
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 9});
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 3});
const optimizer = tf.train.adam(0.05);
modcel.compile({
  optimizer: optimizer,
  loss: 'categoricalCrossentropy',
  metrics: ['accuracy'],
});
// Train.
const lossValues = [];
const accuracyValues = [];
// Call `model.fit` to train the model.
const history = await model.fit(input, output, {epochs: 10});
// Get result
const result = realData.map((input) => model.predict(input));
```

Comment: That looks simple, but I have problems with choosing tensor's shape. Actually, I want my input to be [3, 3, 3] (3x3 pixel) and output to be [3] (single pixel) so there should be 27 neurons at input layer and 3 neurons at output layer. I want to train it passing 100 pixels, so I set the `inputShape: [100, 3, 3, 3]` and create input [100, 3, 3, 3] and output [100, 3] tensors. But it fails with error saying it is expecting 5D array as input.

Comment: Finally I've flattened the input to 2D and it worked. I'm not sure what it does, `await result.data()` returns some crazy numbers (e.g. expecting [0..1] but got -170), but thanks for the jump start.

Comment: Replaced loss with `meanSquaredError`